# Ubuntu command to download https://launchpad.net/~bitcoin/+archive/bitcoin/+packages

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core, ubuntu

What command do I use to get the latest bitcoin package under Ubuntu desktop 12.04 LTS?

Also, what needs to be done to uninstall previous versions?

Answer (score 1):

It's relatively painless

```
sudo apt-add-repository add-repository
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bitcoin-qt
```

How you get rid of the old copy depends on how it was installed, if it was a default install this will probably get rid of that anyway.

Comment: It seems that something is missing from the first line.

Answer (score 1):

This could be found by searching on google and using couple of different queries, nevertheless. Here we go :

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install libtool
sudo apt-get install autotools-dev
sudo apt-get install autoconf
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
sudo apt-get install libdb5.1-dev
sudo apt-get install libdb5.1++-dev
sudo apt-get install libminiupnpc-dev
```

download berkeley db

```
wget http://download.oracle.com/berkeley-db/db-6.0.20.tar.gz
```

unpack

```
tar -xzvf db-6.0.20.tar.gz
```

now build berkeley db

```
../dist/configure --enable-cxx
```

once the process completed

```
make
```

and then

```
make install
```

now download bitcoin repo from github

if you do not have git installed install it by

```
apt-get install git
```

then run

```
git clone git://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin
```

cd bitcoin

```
./autogen.sh
```

let it complete

```
./configure
```

let it complete

```
make
```

now you should have bitcoind in the src folder copy that to usr/bin folder

Answer (score 0):

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install -y git-core build-essential libssl-dev libboost-all-dev libdb5.1-                                      f    dev libdb5.1++-dev libgtk2.0-dev

 git clone https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin.git
 cd bitcoin/src

 make -f makefile.unix clean; make -f makefile.unix USE_UPNP= bitcoind



 USE_UPNP=1 : build but enable by default
 strip bitcoind
```

Then run it with

```
 bitcoind
```

Comment: Also you need to add an rpc username and password to `~/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf`

Comment: Note this build system has changed, there's better documentation in `build-unix.md` in the Bitcoin Core repository.